# Problems with LineBreaks in PHPWord

Tags: php, html, phpword

I'm trying to make a string using foreach

```
foreach ($employees as $program => $employee) {
    $employee_string = $employee_string . $nc->q($employee[$program], NCL::$DATELN) . ', ';

    foreach ($employee as $single) {
        $empList = htmlspecialchars($empList . $single . '<br>');
    }

    $programs_and_employees = htmlspecialchars($programs_and_employees . '«' . $programs[$program] . '»' . ': <br>' . $empList . '<br>');
}

$contract->setValue('programs_and_employees', $programs_and_employees);
```

And instead of linebreacks I get <br>
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: htmlspecialchars is used to convert predefined to HTML entities, why are you using it here? Where are showing this stored information?

Comment: @Alok I tried not to use htmlspecialchars and got an error when opened the document. So I just used it not to get error

Answer (score 0):

I used "\n" instead of 
and then replaced "\n"

```
$programs_and_employees = str_replace("\n", "<w:br/>", $programs_and_employees);
```